# Access Tridion configuration from Event System by different events

Tags: event-system, configuration

Access  Tridion configuration from Event System by different events 
In tridion Event system.  we  see that from event of   SaveEventArgs, It reads  properly from Tridion.ContentManager.config,  while in other events, e.g. SetPublishStateEventArgs  and  PublishEventArgs  it fails to read settings  from  Tridion  config .

I understand  for SaveEventArgs event it use  dllhst3g.exe *32 while for SetPublishStateEventArgs and  PublishEventArgs, both uses tcmpublisher  process . Is there any difference for these two processes to access  Tridion configuration? We are running  on Tridion 2011 .

Comment: I have attempted to answer your question, but it's not very clear. Why are you asking this question. What are the actual problems you are experiencing? How are you detecting that the configuration is accessed?

Comment: Thank you for your  answer   Domini! We  simply would  like  to trigger  push notification service in Tridion event system , in  our case SetPublishState  event. In  applicationSettings  of Tridion.ContentManager.config , we have put settings  values,  like push notification api address, which  can be be read by Tridion events to send  push notification.  In event system .net solution , We use   application settings.

Comment: Then I found  in SaveEventArgs  event it correctly gets  value config settings, while in PublishEventArgs abd SetPublishState , it fails read configuration and direct use values  of compiled application settings from .net solution.
Hope I have made  myself a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

> Your question is not 100% clear, so I will try to answer on the basis of how I understand it. If the question becomes clearer, I will update the answer as appropriate.

In general, the Tridion configuration will be read by any Tridion process that needs to access configuration settings. As it needs to access configuration settings in order to authenticate the user, as far as I know this means every Tridion process.

The configuration data is cached in memory, so if it has already been loaded, you may not see configuration changes come into effect until after the relevant process has been restarted.

I would expect both `SaveEventArgs` and `PublishEventArgs` events to be triggered by processes supporting the user interface. (Note that the `Publish` event takes place when a publish action is entered into the publishing queue.) So in this case dllhst3.exe *32 would make sense. Obviously, if your `Save` action is initiated from the core service, this may be done via a different process.

As you say, the `SetPublishState` event will be triggered by the publisher.